# Separate DHCP from WAN

Tags: networking, lan

I have an ISP connection to router A but would like router B to do all the routing.  So my question is can I have router A serve as both a wireless access point and be physically connected to the ISP via the WAN port while router B does all the routing while connected to router A via the LAN port?

Comment: If the Wi-Fi is on one side of the router B, and the wired LAN is on the other side, they will be two separate networks if you want router B to be the router.. What is on the WAN side of a router, like router B, will need to get its addressing from the WAN, and it is unlikely that your ISP will support that for the Wi-Fi. Better to use router B as the WAN router and set router A to bridge mode and use it as a WAP on the LAN side of router B.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I am fully aware of what's better but for coverage reasons, I want the router with the best coverage in the largest area. Router B also has the best routing options. Router A however is in a smaller confined space that just so happens to be where the Internet connection is physically located.  I just wanted to know if it was possible to have the routing done with router B while being served an Internet connect from router A that will simultaneously serve as an access point for router B.

Comment: Your Wi-Fi on router A will not be served by router B through its WAN port, it would have to be on the LAN side of router B, but router B could then not be the router since it can only route between WAN and LAN. You are trying to do something for which you have the wrong equipment. You need a router and WAP(s).

Answer (score 1):

Not practically, no.

Packets need to be directed THROUGH a router - in this case, the router connected to the ISP.    If you have very expensive routers (not home user routers) it might be possible to construct a complex mechanism to bridge routers in such a way as to make this happen, but it would be a Rube Goldberg (unnecessarily difficult and impractical) solution.